# Dominion Prosperity play out treasures

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-nocturne

I have a question regarding the dominion extension prosperity, especially the new treasure-cards

Venture: "When you play this, reveal cards from your deck until you reveal a Treasure. Discard the other cards. Play that Treasure"

I really don't understand these instructions, let me explain how I understand the buy-phase

1. I take a card from the stack, e.g. a market for 5 money
2. I pay the money for the card, e.g. and play out a venture and two silvers, other treasure-cards on my hand I ignore.

Now the venture-card doesn't make any sense, as well as most of the other treasure cards in the expansion. If I have already bought a card, why do I need the venture? Am I right that this card only makes sense, if you have more than 1 buy?

Or am I completely wrong about how the buy-phase works. My SO thinks that you first play out *all* the treasure-cards in your hand and then take a card from the stack .... but what if I have e.g. 10 idols ("When you play this, if you then have an odd number of Idols in play, receive a Boon; if an even number, each other player gains a Curse.") and only buy a silver from it, does my opponent have to take a curse (because I have 10 idols) or do I get a boon (because I have paid 3 of them to buy a silver)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you need to buy a card when playing treasures in Dominion?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/do-you-need-to-buy-a-card-when-playing-treasures-in-dominion)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Even though there is some overlap in that the same set of rules answers both questions; I think the question being asked is very different in each case.

Comment: Despite the title, the subject of this post seems to be "How does the buy phase work?", which seems to be a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: The other question is specifically asking whether or not buying a card is mandatory. How treasure cards work and the order that things happen in the buy phase seems like a separate issue.

Answer (score 9):

You are playing the buy phase incorrectly.

In the buy phase, you always play all of your treasure cards, one at a time, before you buy any card. In fact, you are not allowed to play any more treasure cards after you buy a card.

You never play specific treasure cards to buy specific cards. Don't think of treasures as the currency you use to buy cards. Rather, treasure cards are just cards like action cards are, except that you play them in your buy phase rather than in your action phase. When you play a Silver, it produces $2, just like how playing a Festival produces $2. After you have played all of your treasures, you will have some total amount of money available, produced by all the actions and treasures that you have played. Then you proceed to spend that money on cards you want to buy.

So when you play Venture, you first get $1 added to your pool of money, and then you reveal cards until you reveal another treasure card and play that as well.

If you play 3 Idols, you play them one at a time and fully deal with each Idol when you play it. So the first one will give you a boon, the second one will give your opponents a curse, and the third one will give you another boon. Only after you are done playing all of your treasures and dealing with all of their effects do you buy cards. The treasure cards and the instructions on them never care if you actually buy anything. You can play a bunch of Idols just for the extra benefit and then never buy a card.

From the base-game rulebook (second edition):

> First you can play any number of Treasure cards from your hand, in any order. Treasure cards say "Treasure" on the bottom and have a yellow banner. You play one by moving it to the "in play"
> area; you probably will not announce your Treasures, though you can if you want. The Treasures have no text, just a big coin with a number on it. You get that many coins to spend this turn - one coin for a Copper, two for a Silver, three for a Gold, indicated as $1, $2, $3. The amount is also in the corners at the top of Treasures. You do not have to play every Treasure in your hand (but only get $ this turn for the Treasures you play).

> Then, you can buy one card, costing as much as you have or less.

> You cannot go back and play more Treasures after buying a card; first play Treasures, then buy.

The treasure cards in Prosperity follow the same rules as the treasure cards in the base game; it's just that in the base game; no treasure cards have effects other than producing some amount of money.

Comment: Thanks, question regarding the Idol, so you have to play out the treasures one after another and not all at the same time, so it is actually boon - curse - boon - curse depending on how many idols you have, am I right? Cause I thought it depends on the total number of idols,

Comment: @Féileacán That is correct; you always play treasure cards one at a time and do everything it says when you play it. It's just that with the standard treasures doing so never makes a difference so people tend to play them all at once to save time.

Comment: And with idol you can see the order matters - one of the boons is trash a card from your hand - you'll want to play the idols begore your copper so that you might be able to trash the copper.

Comment: Order is also relevant for many other treasure cards such as Counterfeit where you probably want to play your ventures first and Fortune or Horn of Plenty where you'll likely want to play the venture lastish.